# Populate files into a listbox from a folder in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm a newbie in C# and I have 2 Listboxes l-->istBox1 and listBox2 and I want to load files from folder into these listboxes.
I tried like this :
`listBox1:`

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TestLoadFiles");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.rtdl");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                listbox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }

        }
```

`listBox2:`

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TestLoadFiles");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.dlz");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                listbox2.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
```

when i run the form, the files from the folder is not displaying???

Comment: Nice. and now what is your question?

Comment: what's the issue? in selectedindexchanged handler for listbox1, you are again populating listbox1

Comment: you already did it, actually ...

Comment: you really using selected index change event on listBox1 and populating to listBox1? What you need is just use listBox2.Items.Add...

Comment: I have 2 listboxes and I want to load 2 different files from the same folder. so, when i run the form, the files from the folder the listbox is empty.

Comment: @Habib.OSU: yes, i'm sorry, i just elaborated the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged, update the listbox against some button click, otherwise your code looks fine. Initially you probably don't have any item in your listbox and that's why SelectedIndexChanged doesn't get fired when you click on it.

Edit: (Since the question has been edited, I will update my answer)
To pouplate your listboxes with Files, you should do that, in some event other than SelectedIndexChanged. Because at the start of your application your listboxes are empty and SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired when there are items in the listbox and user click on it. You may create the following function

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Now you may call this function with your listbox in some event against a button click or form load. e.g.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateListBox(listbox1, @"C:\TestLoadFiles", "*.rtld");
    PopulateListBox(listbox2, @"C:\TestLoadFiles", "*.other");
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm a stupid. so this listbox event will fire when there are items in the listbox and user click on it. Thank u, then how can i populate the list from the folder??

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ, see my updated answer, you can use the method

Comment: Yes you missing `using System.IO;`

Comment: Now, I know to load files I should include System.IO;

Answer (score 1):

This might work ;)

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TestLoadFiles");
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.rtdl");
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        listbox2.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong event i suppose. Move that code to the constructor of your form/control or attach it to an event of another control. Repopulating the listBox on SelectedIndexChanged when the initial state of the listbox is empty does not make sense.